# load flexslider from ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, flexslider

I'm trying to load a flexslider from ajax. It works when I point directly on the page containing the slider, but from ajax the slider doesn't load.

Here is my ajax page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Ajax Event Handler For Categorie Demo
var $menu1 = $('#navDemo02');



function success(){

    $('div.ajaxContent').hide();
  $('div.ajaxContent').show(200);
}

function ajaxCallTimeout(index){
var url = 'categorie/0'+(index+1)+'.php';
 $('div.ajaxContent').load(url, success);
}
function ajaxCategorie(){
    var index = $menu1.find('li a').index(this);
     $('div.ajaxContent').html('<p style="color:#4CC3EC; text-align:center; margin-top:45px;">Loading...<img src="img/loading.gif" /></p>');
    switch(index){
        case 0 :

              $('div.ajaxContent').stop().animate({marginTop: 0}, 1000,'linear', function(){ajaxCallTimeout(index)});
        break;
        case 1 : 

              $('div.ajaxContent').stop().animate({marginTop: 0}, 1000,'linear', function(){ajaxCallTimeout(index)});
        break;
        case 2 : 

              $('div.ajaxContent').stop().animate({marginTop: 0}, 1000,'linear',function(){ajaxCallTimeout(index)});
        break;
        case 3 : 

              $('div.ajaxContent').stop().animate({marginTop: 0}, 1000,'linear', function(){ajaxCallTimeout(index)});
        break;
        case 4 : 

              $('div.ajaxContent').stop().animate({marginTop:0}, 1000,'linear', function(){ajaxCallTimeout(index)});
        break;
        case 5 : 

              $('div.ajaxContent').stop().animate({marginTop: 0}, 1000,'linear', function(){ajaxCallTimeout(index)});
        break;
        case 6 : 

              $('div.ajaxContent').stop().animate({marginTop: 0}, 1000,'linear', function(){ajaxCallTimeout(index)});
        break;


    }
}

$menu1.find('li a').bind('click', ajaxCategorie);
```

});

Here is the script for the slider

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>

<script defer src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  SyntaxHighlighter.all();
});
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing or point me out a tutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the flexslider() function on the class 'before' loading the mentioned class into DOM?

When you click on the link to make the ajax call, the javascript on that page has already run its course. Now when you make the ajax call, the script does not re-run to assign flexslider on the new class(that has been called in via ajax) again.

If this is true, you could try moving the flexslider script into the page to which you are making the ajax call.

Comment: could you elaborate how to re-run it? i think i have a similar problem shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194457/js-error-after-ajax-get-load